# Using regular expressions to multiply and sum numeric string characters contained in a hash of mixed numeric strings

Tags: ruby

Without getting too much into biology, Proteins are made of Amino Acids. Each of the 20 Amino Acids that make up Proteins are represented by characters in a sequence. Each Amino Acid char has a different chemical formula, which I represent as strings. For example, `"M"` has a formula of `"C5H11NO2S"`

Given the 20 different formulas (and the varying frequency of each amino acid chars in a protein sequence) I want to compile all 20 of them into a single formula that will yield the total formula for the protein.

So first: multiply each formula by the frequency of its char in the sequence

Second : sum together all multiplied formulas into one formula.

To accomplish this, I first tried multiplying each amino acid char frequency in the sequence by the numbers in the chemical formula. I did this using `.tally`

```
sequence ="MGAAARTLRLALGLLLLATLLRPADACSCSPVHPQQAFCNADVVIRAKAVSEKEVDSGNDIYGNPIKRIQYEIKQIKMFKGPEKDIEFI"
```

```
sequence.chars.string.tally --> {"M"=>2, "G"=>5, "A"=>11, "R"=>5, "T"=>2, "L"=>9, "P"=>5, "D"=>5, "C"=>3, "S"=>4, "V"=>5, "H"=>1, "Q"=>4, "F"=>3, "N"=>3, "I"=>8, "K"=>7, "E"=>5, "Y"=>2}
```

Then, I listed all the amino acids chars and formulas into a hash

`hash_of_formulas = {"A"=>"C3H7NO2", "R"=>"C6H14N4O2", "N"=>"C4H8N2O3", "D"=>"C4H7NO4", "C"=>"C3H7NO2S", "E"=>"C5H9NO4", "Q"=>"C5H10N2O3", "G"=>"C2H5NO2", "H"=>"C6H9N3O2", "I"=>"C6H13NO2", "L"=>"C6H13NO2", "K"=>"C6H14N2O2", "M"=>"C5H11NO2S", "F"=>"C9H11NO2", "P"=>"C5H9NO2", "S"=>"C3H7NO3", "T"=>"C4H9NO3", "W"=>"C11H12N2O2", "Y"=>"C9H11NO3", "V"=>"C5H11NO2"}`

An example of what the process for my overall goal is: 
In the `sequence` , `"M"` occurs twice so `"C5H11NO2S"` will become `"C10H22N2O4S2"`.  `"C"` has a formula of `"C3H7NO2S"` occurs 3 times: In the `sequence` so `"C3H7NO2S"` becomes `"C9H21N3O6S3"`

So, Summing together `"C10H22N2O4S2"` and `"C9H21N3O6S3"`  will yield  `"C19H43N5O10S5"`

How can I repeat the process of multiplying each formula by its frequency and then summing together all multiplied formulas?
 I know that I could use regex for multiplying a formula by its frequency for an individual string using

```
formula_multiplied_by_frequency = "C5H11NO2S".gsub(/\d+/) { |x| x.to_i * 4}
```

But I'm not sure of any methods to use regex on strings embedded within hashes

Comment: Please explain how (M) `"C5H11NO2S"` becomes `"C10H22N2O4S2"`, where M has a frequency of `2`.  I understand `5 -> 10`, `11 -> 22` and `02 -> 04`, but do not understand why there is a `2` after `N` and a `2` after `S`. My answer is presently incorrect because I don't understand all the rules.

Comment: Ah,  well first I want to say I appreciate you answering every question I've posted on stackoverflow despite them being not always being super clear cut in what I'm asking.

Comment: But the reason for adding a 2 after N or S is because in chemistry, a single element in a formula is just represented as the element. So water is made up 2 Hydrogens and 1 Oxygen. And so its chemical formula is written as H2O. If an oxygen is added to water, it's formula is written as H2O and I really suggest you don't drink it.  But this convention in chemistry probably makes it a lot harder to  program.

Comment: But I could use it to bleach my hair? (I think you left off a `2`.)

Comment: yes, and yes I did, Now in the answer you provided is there a way to sum up all the formulas generated in the hash?  something like

Comment: ```"C10H22NO4S2"```  + ```"C10H25NO105"``` +  ```"C33H77NO2211"``` + ```"C30H70N20O105"``` + ```"C8H18NO62" ``` ..etc, etc ?

Comment: What is, for example, `"C10H22NO4S2" + "C10H25NO105"`? `"C20H47N2O109S2"`?

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand... "N" in "C5H11NO2S" is effectively "N1". (I also misread oh as zero.) So if we inserted a "1" after every naked letter, did the math, then removed all the "1"s in the answer (if any), we should have the correct result?

Comment: What I meant by ```"C10H22NO4S2" ```+``` "C10H25NO105"``` + ```"C33H77NO2211"``` +``` "C30H70N20O105"``` +  ``` "C8H18NO62"``` is that you computed the sum formula for each amino acid based on frequency of each amino acid char in the sequence.  But what I am after is the formula for a protein. For example a protein that has sequence of ```MCMPCFTTDHQMARKCDDCCGGKGRGKCYGPQCLCR ``` has a formula of  ```C158H249N53O47S11```   So far in your answer you have all the pieces, now you have to bring all the formulas in your  hash together into one formula.

Comment: Yes you could write all the naked letters (N, S) as N1 and S1 then remove the 1 after the final formula has been computed.

Comment: OK. I think I understand, and am working on it. Should take long.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: "Should take long"? :D

Comment: It's taken a very long time already. I've posted a partial answer. Please let me know if it provides what you are looking for so far.

Comment: "But I'm not sure of any methods to use regex on strings embedded within hashes" – You use the same methods you use everywhere else. The string methods don't care how you store the string. They only care it's a string.

Comment: Yes it's also getting late on this side of the continent and I drifted off, and will get back to you tommorrow as well. I greatly appreciate your efforts and support.  Maybe, just maybe I provoked some interest in you and other who see this question for bioinformatics.

Answer (score 1):

**Givens**

We are given a string representing a protein comprised of amino acids:

```
sequence = "MGAAARTLRLALGLLLLATLLRPADACSCSPVHPQQAFCNADVVIR" + 
           "AKAVSEKEVDSGNDIYGNPIKRIQYEIKQIKMFKGPEKDIEFI"
```

and a hash that contains the formulas of amino acids:

```
formulas = {
  "A"=>"C3H7NO2", "R"=>"C6H14N4O2", "N"=>"C4H8N2O3", "D"=>"C4H7NO4", 
  "C"=>"C3H7NO2S", "E"=>"C5H9NO4", "Q"=>"C5H10N2O3", "G"=>"C2H5NO2", 
  "H"=>"C6H9N3O2", "I"=>"C6H13NO2", "L"=>"C6H13NO2", "K"=>"C6H14N2O2", 
  "M"=>"C5H11NO2S", "F"=>"C9H11NO2", "P"=>"C5H9NO2", "S"=>"C3H7NO3", 
  "T"=>"C4H9NO3", "W"=>"C11H12N2O2", "Y"=>"C9H11NO3", "V"=>"C5H11NO2"
}
```

**Obtain counts of atoms in each amino acid**

As a first step we can calculate the numbers of each atom in each amino acid:

```
counts = formulas.transform_values do |s|
  s.scan(/[CHNOS]\d*/).
    each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
    h[s[0]] = s.size == 1 ? 1 : s[1..-1].to_i
  end
end
  #=> {"A"=>{"C"=>3, "H"=>7,  "N"=>1, "O"=>2},
  #    "R"=>{"C"=>6, "H"=>14, "N"=>4, "O"=>2},
  #    ...
  #    "M"=>{"C"=>5, "H"=>11, "N"=>1, "O"=>2, "S"=>1} 
  #    ...
  #    "V"=>{"C"=>5, "H"=>11, "N"=>1, "O"=>2}}
```

**Compute formula for protein**

Then it's simply:

```
def protein_formula(sequence, counts)
  sequence.each_char.
           with_object("C"=>0, "H"=>0, "N"=>0, "O"=>0, "S"=>0) do |c,h|
    counts[c].each { |aa,cnt| h[aa] += cnt }
  end.each_with_object('') { |(aa,nbr),s| s << "#{aa}#{nbr}" }
end
```

```
protein_formula(sequence, counts)
  #=> "C434H888N120O213S5"
```

Another example:

```
protein_formula("MCMPCFTTDHQMARKCDDCCGGKGRGKCYGPQCLCR", count)
  #=> "C158H326N52O83S11"
```

**Explanation of calculation of `counts`**

This calculation:

```
counts = formulas.transform_values do |s|
  s.scan(/[CHNOS]\d*/).each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
    h[s[0]] = s.size == 1 ? 1 : s[1..-1].to_i
  end
end
```

uses the method [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values). It will return a hash having the same keys as the hash `formulas`, with the values of those keys in `formula` modified by `transform_values`'s block. For example, `formulas["A"]` (`"C3H7NO2"`) is "transformed" to the hash `{"C"=>3, "H"=>7,  "N"=>1, "O"=>2}` in the hash that is returned, `counts`.

`transform_values` passes each value of `formulas` to the block and sets the block variable equal to it. The first value passed is `"C3H7NO2"`, so it sets:

```
s = "C3H7NO2"
```

We can write the block calculation more simply:

```
h = {}
s.scan(/[CHNOS]\d*/).each do |s|
  h[s[0]] = s.size == 1 ? 1 : s[1..-1].to_i
end
h
```

(Once you understand this calculation, which I explain below, see [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to understand why I used that method in my solution.)

After initializing `h` to an empty hash, the following calculations are performed:

```
h = {}
a = s.scan(/[CHNOS]\d*/)
  #=> ["C3", "H7", "N", "O2"]
```

`a` is computed using [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with the *regular expression* `/[CHNOS]\d*/`. That regular expression, or *regex*, matches exactly one character in the *character class* `[CHNOS]` followed by zero of more (`*`) digits (`\d`). It therefore separates the string `"C3H7NO2"` into the substrings that are returned in the array shown under the calculation of `a` above . Continuing,

```
a.each do |s|
  h[s[0]] = s.size == 1 ? 1 : s[1..-1].to_i
end
```

changes `h` to the following:

```
h #=> {"C"=>3, "H"=>7, "N"=>1, "O"=>2}
```

The block variable `s` is initially set equal to the first element of `a` that is passed to `each`'s block:

```
s = "C3"
```

then we compute:

```
h[s[0]] = s.size == 1 ? 1 : s[1..-1].to_i
 h["A"] = 2 == 1 ? 1 : "3".to_i
        = false ? 1 : 3
        3
```

This is repeated for each element of `a`.

**Exclamation of construction of formula for the protein**

We can simplify the following code<sup>1</sup>:

```
sequence.each_char.with_object("C"=>0, "H"=>0, "N"=>0, "O"=>0) do |c,h|
  counts[c].each { |aa,cnt| h[aa] += cnt }
end.each_with_object('') { |(aa,nbr),s| s << "#{aa}#{nbr}" }
```

to more or less the following:

```
h = { "C"=>0, "H"=>0, "N"=>0, "O"=>0, "S"=>0 }
ch = sequence.chars
  #=> ["M", "G", "A",..., "F", "I"] 
ch.each do |c|
  counts[c].each { |aa,cnt| h[aa] += cnt }
end
h #=> {"C"=>434, "H"=>888, "N"=>120, "O"=>213, "S"=>5}
```

When the first value of `ch` (`"M"`) is passed to `each`'s block (when `h = { "C"=>0, "H"=>0, "N"=>0, "O"=>0, "S"=>0 }`), the following calculations are performed:

```
c = "M"
g = counts[c]
  #=> {"C"=>10, "H"=>22, "N"=>2, "O"=>4, "S"=>1}  
g.each { |aa,cnt| h[aa] += cnt }
h #=> {"C"=>10, "H"=>22, "N"=>2, "O"=>4, "S"=>1}
```

Lastly, (when `h #=> {"C"=>434, "H"=>888, "N"=>120, "O"=>213, "S"=>5}`)

```
s = ''
h.each { |aa,nbr| s << "#{aa}#{nbr}" }
s #=> "C434H888N120O213S5"
```

When `aa = "C"` and `nbr = 434`,

```
"#{aa}#{nbr}"
  #=> "C434"
```

is appended to the string `s`.

<sup>1. (`("C"=>0, "H"=>0, "N"=>0, "O"=>0)` is shorthand for `({"C"=>0, "H"=>0, "N"=>0, "O"=>0})`.</sup>

Comment: Late reply, but it works and I appreciate the help once again. But me being a novice programmer, I don't understand all the syntax you put forth. ```.transform_values```,   ```h[s[0]] = s.size == 1 ? 1 : s[1..-1].to_i ``` I know is a ternary but what is it doing  by saying that the inner hash size is equal to one? I have more questions and if you are willing to walk me through more of them that would be wonderful.

Comment: I provided the explanation you requested. As you are new to Ruby it might not be completely clear, of course. Feel free to follow up with questions.

Comment: the explanation given was helpful, but I did not get the same answer of ```C158H249N53O47S11``` for ```MCMPCFTTDHQMARKCDDCCGGKGRGKCYGPQCLCR```, instead I got ```C158H326N52O83``` Also, the hash object ```{ "C"=>0, "H"=>0, "N"=>0, "O"=>0 }``` did not include the ```S=>0``` since two Amino Acids (M and C) both have one sulfur atom in them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I missed sulfur. I repaired my answer.

Comment: Are you entering the single element formulas as is such as the ```N``` and ```S``` in ```C3H7NO2S``` or are you manually editing each formula with single elements to include 1's such as ```C3H7N1O2S1``` because, I'm still not getting the right answer for the formula for ```MCMPCFTTDHQMARKCDDCCGGKGRGKCYGPQCLCR``` using your code.  (note this protein is called Chlorotoxin if you want to google it and the info I found on it was from https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/86278273#section=2D-Structure  )

Comment: I'm seeing if its my own data i got for the formulas, which it partially is. I got the formulas from the Amino acids as stand alone molecules, but there formula changes when they link up to form proteins. with that said, I'm getting way closer using...

Comment: ```res_f_with_ones =  {
    "A"=>"C3H5N1O1", "R"=>"C6H12N4O1", "N"=>"C4H6N2O2", "D"=>"C4H5N1O3",
    "C"=>"C3H5N1O1S1", "E"=>"C5H7N1O3", "Q"=>"C5H8N2O2", "G"=>"C2H3N1O1",
    "H"=>"C6H7N3O1", "I"=>"C6H11N1O1", "L"=>"C6H11N1O1", "K"=>"C6H12N2O1",
    "M"=>"C5H9N1O1S1", "F"=>"C9H9N1O1", "P"=>"C5H7N1O1", "S"=>"C3H5N1O2",
    "T"=>"C4H7N1O2", "W"=>"C11H10N2O1", "Y"=>"C9H9N1O2", "V"=>"C5H9N1O1"
}```

Comment: Regarding your first sentence, the former. I see the result for Chlorotoxin is not the same as that shown at the link, but @Amandan and I get the same (incorrect) result, suggesting the problem lies with the hash `formulas`.

Comment: When setting `formulas = res_f_with_ones`, the result for Chlorotoxin is found to be "C158H254N52O47S11", still different from that given at the link: "C158H249N53O47S11".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the to provide the total formula for a given protein sequence. Here's how I'd do it:

```
NUCLEOTIDES = {"A"=>"C3H7NO2", "R"=>"C6H14N4O2", "N"=>"C4H8N2O3", "D"=>"C4H7NO4", "C"=>"C3H7NO2S", "E"=>"C5H9NO4", "Q"=>"C5H10N2O3", "G"=>"C2H5NO2", "H"=>"C6H9N3O2", "I"=>"C6H13NO2", "L"=>"C6H13NO2", "K"=>"C6H14N2O2", "M"=>"C5H11NO2S", "F"=>"C9H11NO2", "P"=>"C5H9NO2", "S"=>"C3H7NO3", "T"=>"C4H9NO3", "W"=>"C11H12N2O2", "Y"=>"C9H11NO3", "V"=>"C5H11NO2"}
NUCLEOTIDE_COMPOSITIONS = NUCLEOTIDES.each_with_object({}) { |(nucleotide, formula), compositions|
  compositions[nucleotide] = formula.scan(/([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d*)/).map { |element, count| [element, count.empty? ? 1 : count.to_i] }.to_h
}

def formula(sequence)
  sequence.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |nucleotide, final_counts|
    NUCLEOTIDE_COMPOSITIONS[nucleotide].each { |element, element_count|
      final_counts[element] += element_count
    }
  }.map { |element, element_count|
    "#{element}#{element_count.zero? ? "" : element_count}"
  }.join
end

sequence = "MGAAARTLRLALGLLLLATLLRPADACSCSPVHPQQAFCNADVVIRAKAVSEKEVDSGNDIYGNPIKRIQYEIKQIKMFKGPEKDIEFI"
p formula(sequence)
# => "C434H888N51O213S"
```

You can't use regexp to multiply things. You can use it to parse a formula, but then it's on you and regular Ruby to do the math. The first job is to prepare a composition lookup by breaking down each nucleotide formula. Once we have a composition hash for each nucleotide, we can iterate over a nucleotide sequence, and add up all the elements of each nucleotide.

BTW, `tally` is not particularly useful here, since `tally` will need to iterate over the sequence, and then you have to iterate over `tally` anyway — and there is no aggregate operation going on that can't be done going over each letter independently.

EDIT: I probably made the regexp slightly more complicated that it needs to be, but it should parse stuff like `CuSO4` correctly. I don't know if it's an accident or not that all nucleotides are only composed of elements with a single-character symbol... :P )